# Mysql Error 1356 - Views

Tags: mysql

When i'll try create some but when i call it appears the error 1356:

**Creating the View**

```
CREATE VIEW monitoring_consult AS (
    SELECT 
        m.id,
        account.valor AS 'phone_number',
        IF((c.valor REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' OR c.valor IS NULL) AND cn.short_name IS NOT NULL, cn.short_name, c.valor) AS 'category',
        IF(pn.id IS NOT NULL, pn.id, p.valor) AS 'provider',
        n.valor AS 'nominal',
        m.last_page,
        pn.name AS 'provider_name',
        IF(pay.valor is null, 'Uncompleted', pay.valor) AS 'payment',
        timeEnd,
        DATE_FORMAT(m.timeEnd, '%d/%m/%Y') as 'date'
    FROM
        monitoring AS m
            LEFT JOIN feature   AS account ON m.id = account.id AND account.valor IS NOT NULL AND (account.page = 'PV') AND account.type = 'send'
            LEFT JOIN feature   AS c    ON m.id = c.id_monitoring   AND c.valor IS NOT NULL AND (c.page = 'MA' OR c.page = 'IN') AND c.type = 'select'
            LEFT JOIN feature   AS p    ON m.id = p.id_monitoring   AND p.page = 'PO' AND p.valor IS NOT NULL AND p.type = 'select'
            LEFT JOIN feature   AS n    ON m.id = n.id_monitoring   AND n.valor IS NOT NULL AND n.page = 'OAP' AND n.type = 'select'
            LEFT JOIN feature   AS pay  ON m.id = pay.id_monitoring AND m.last_page = 'OK' AND pay.type = 'userAction'  AND pay.name = 'paymentStatus' AND pay.valor = 'Completed'
            LEFT JOIN terminais AS term ON m.id_terminal = term.id
            LEFT JOIN provider  AS pn   ON (p.valor = pn.id) OR (c.valor REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' AND c.valor = pn.id)
            LEFT JOIN category  AS cn   ON pn.id_category = cn.id
        group by m.id
        having category is not null
)
```

**Calling the view:**

```
select * from monitoring_consult
```

**Return:**

```
Error Code: 1356. View 'qiwi.monitoring_consult' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them
```

Mysql Version - 5.5.32-log

Do someone know why this happened?

Comment: Have you simply tried to 'use qiwi'? This way the view knows which database to use. I think this is your problem...

Comment: Also, are you using more views in this view?

Comment: Not this my frist view. I try use qiwi but it didn't work

Comment: I meant to add 'USE qiwi' to the create view statement to Ensure its using the database you want and not the session database you are in

Comment: :/ it doesn't work. I know that consume very traffic but use sub query to resolve this problem.

Comment: You can't put a USE statement inside a view, anyway. They run in the database that was current when they were defined.  Question, though... does the query defining the view work if you just execute it, starting with the first SELECT, while you are logged in as the same user that defined the view?

Comment: Yes i realized the test with USE and with same user but it didn't work. I think that is bug of Mysql.

Answer (score 10):

this particular problem happen to me every time i imported a mysqldump export, with automatic views creation inside it,

such problem came out because of the creation of the view in the mysqldump (when you reimport again), with "SQL SECURITY DEFINER",

i don't known if it is a mysql bug, but for me deleting and applying new permission to the view, does not solve the problem, recreating the view without the "SQL SECURITY DEFINER", solve my problem, i hope this is your case.

Ciao.

Comment: Maybe the Definer lose privileges...  Re-creating with a good one correct the bug.

Comment: Hello, I don't know if this topic its closed but I have now the problem, but when I give right click on the view and remove sql security definer and then I give click on apply, always appears the sql security definer

Answer (score 1):

These are the cases

1. MySQL loggined user has not the privilege view the monitoring_consult view
2. Any of your joined table not exist
3. Any of your field that you are trying fetch not exist ( You might be deleted )

Comment: Then in the frist case if i didn't have privilege the right witch when i'll create some view appears that i don't have permission to create it.

The second, third case i tested this query without view and it works.

Comment: @GuilhermeSoares Is that db you have exported from any other DB ?

Comment: I don't export from other database.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error code and was able to pin it down somewhat. It appears to arise when an object two (or more?) levels down is no longer available. Here is some code to recreate the issue.

```
create table `table1` (`id` int(11), `col1` varchar(16);
insert into `table1` (`id`, `col1`) values (1, 'Foo'), (2, 'Bar');

create view `view_sub` as SELECT `id`, `col1` from `table1`;
# if you drop here you'll get error code 1146: table1 doesn't exist

create view `view_err` as SELECT `id`, `col1` from `view_sub`;
drop table `table1`;

select * from `view_err`
# should get you error code 1356: references invalid table(s), etc
```

I don't know if anything in your from clause is a view, but the (what appears to be) typo of `terminais` may be causing it.

Answer (score 0):

When creating the view, try to specify a definer like this:

```
    CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `user`@`%` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `monitoring_consult` AS ...
```

where the DEFINER `user`must have the appropriate rights to any table that is linked to the view

Answer (score 0):

Hi I got this error after changing my database model. Happened that an existing view referenced non existing fields.

So the solution was delete the current view and create a new one, considering the new model instead of focusing on user privileges.

Hope it helps to someone :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. While I still don't know what it caused the problem, because none of the tables the view uses had been changed.

My solution was to drop the old view and create a new one this time I specified at the top of my view the following.

```
use databasename;
```

Answer (score 0):

This message can sometimes be misleading. I was getting the same warning even though i had made sure that the definer user had the correct permissions and all the referenced tables/fields were OK.

After running

```
show create view viewName;
```

I noticed that the output contained `1 warning` so after that I run

```
show warnings;
```

And that showed me the actual problem.